# Does Apple add the background device to my uploaded screenshots for Appstore connect or do I have to add the device?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, screenshot

I am uploading screenshots to Appstore connect to submit my app. Does Apple add the device to the screenshots that people see on the Appstore?

EDIT

[the image is a screenshot of an app on appstore. I have circled out one of the screenshots in red which has an iphone device in the background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8woka.jpg)

Comment: can you share an example of what you mean by "background device" ?

Comment: Apple displays the images exactly as you upload them. If you want to show your app in a device frame then you have to do that yourself.

Comment: oh ok understood. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As @Paulw11 has mentioned in comments. **No Apple won't do it for you**. You will have to create these images yourself. Check below mentioned websites. I haven't used them but they might help you.

1. https://shotbot.io
2. https://medium.com/appmanager/best-12-tools-to-create-amazing-screenshots-for-your-mobile-apps-2018-1cbf6f8660ba